# Search within a search

Tags: command-line, grep, pipe

I've gotten used to using `grep` for my command line searches and wanted to know how to successfully do a search using the result of another search.

Here's my attempt, where I am looking for 'tool' within my result:

```
grep tool | grep -rl embed=
```

This returns some results and then the console hangs. Are there any simple/elegant solutions to this?

Comment: Your console hangs, because the first `grep` needs a file (or stdin using a pipe) to read from.

Comment: I could not quite understand what you are trying to accomplish with this command. First part, i.e., `grep tool` is looking for word `tool` in the `stdin`, then you are looking for file names, recursively, contaning keyword `embed=`. This can not possibly yield anything for you. If you haven't thought about it, second grep is taking first one's output as its input. If that input is just lines, `-r` or `-l` switches are irrelevant.

Comment: @MelBurslan thanks, so in the second grep (in this wrong example), where does the first grep's output get used? Which order does everything happen?

Comment: Please see my answer below and if necessary modify your question with what you are trying to do, in plain English. Because it still doesn't make a lick of sense to me.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of `stdin` and `stderr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) run from left to right. More precisely, the *processes* run in parallel, but the *data* flows from left to right: the output of the command on the left becomes the input of the command on the right.

Here the command on the left is `grep tool`. Since you're passing a single argument to `grep`, it's searching in its standard input. Since you haven't redirected the standard input, `grep` is reading from the terminal: it's waiting for you to type.

To search in a file, use

```
grep tool path/to/file | …
```

To search in a directory recursively, use

```
grep -r tool path/to/directory | …
```

You can filter the results to list only the lines that contain `embed=`. Drop the `-l` and `-r` options, they make no sense when the input is coming from standard input.

```
grep -r tool path/to/directory | grep 'embed='
```

This lists lines containing both `tool` and `embed=` (in either order). An alternative method with simpler plumbing would be to do a single search with an or pattern; this is always possible, but if the patterns can overlap (not the case here), the pattern can get very complicated.

```
grep -E -r 'tool.*embed=|embed=.*tool' path/to/directory
```

If you wanted to list *files* containing both `tool` and `embed=`, you'd need a different command structure, with the first `grep` listing file names (`-l`) and the second one receiving those file names as *arguments*, not as input. Converting standard input into command line arguments what the [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) command is for.

```
grep -lZ -r tool path/to/directory | xargs -0 grep -l 'embed='
```

Comment: For a POSIX way to do the last command, you could use `find path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -q tool {} \; -exec grep -l embed= {} +`

Comment: Also, I wish I could upvote this more than once—it is the only answer that actually *answers* the OP's use case and addresses his obvious confusion about left to right.

Answer (score 4):

This command is going to search for `foo` in the file `filename` and in the results for `bar`:

`grep foo filename | grep bar`

An alternative would be with awk:
`awk '/foo/ && /bar/' filename`

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep in different ways, for instance:

```
cat myfile | grep keyword
```

This above example will dump the file to `stdout`. The pipe character `|` will take that output and feed it to `grep keyword` command as `stdin`. In the end, the lines in myfile containing `keyword` will be written to the `stdout`, which  is generally terminal screen. This is a very ineffective use of resources, the same result can be accomplished with this command as well:

```
grep keyword myfile
```

if you want to use `grep` in a cascaded menner, here is how it goes:

```
grep keyword1 myfile | grep keyword2
```

This time, first `grep` command, finds the lines containing `keyword1` in myfile. Second grep command takes the output of the first one, and searches for `keyword2` in those. Effectively, you are looking for lines containing both `keyword1` and `keyword2` in `myfile`.

you can multiply these commands with different command line switches to find what exactly you are looking for, using more than one pipe. If you can elaborate what you are trying to do with your command in the original question in plain English, myself or someone else can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are trying to do is logical AND.  `grep` is a line matching tool, so in terms of a line patter1 AND patter2 logic mean they are going to be on the same line  ; when you search a file , where you want to find line with one term and another on the same line, you can use regular expression `grep 'pattern1.*pattern2' input_file.txt`

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'xieerqi.*firefox'
xieerqi   5069  2616  7 17:43 ?        00:07:25 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
xieerqi  24317  6901  0 19:22 pts/19   00:00:00 grep xieerqi.*firefox
```

In this example, instead of searching all processes with my username and then piping to another `grep` that filters `firefox` processes.

For more, refer to this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/)

Comment: This solution only finds lines with the patterns in that order.

Comment: @JakobLenfers That's a valid point , but one can always repeat the search reversing the order or using the `pattern1|pattern2` structure. Actually, I just realized that Gilles already proposed the same solution, using `or` and reversing the order of the pattern. Typically what users do is two pipes to `grep` , so cases where people use multiple patterns to search is not so frequent. So that's an OK solution, but for more patterns probably awk is better